# Build failed with an exception Could not resolve io.github.g00fy2:versioncompare:1.5.0

Tags: maven, gradle, ionic-framework, ionic5

> cordova.cmd build android --release
> The "" tags were detected and are no longer supported. Please migrate to the "preference" tag "AndroidWindowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon".
> cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter: Processed 34 source files in 588ms
> Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
> ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\iamsh\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (recommended setting)
> ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\android-sdk-windows (DEPRECATED)
> Using Android SDK: C:\android-sdk-windows
> Subproject Path: CordovaLib
> Subproject Path: app

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Webtrikon\quickchicken\platforms\android\build.gradle' line: 21
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Quick Chicken'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration 'classpath'.
> Could not resolve io.github.g00fy2:versioncompare:1.5.0.
> Required by:
> unspecified:unspecified:unspecified
> > Could not resolve io.github.g00fy2:versioncompare:1.5.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/github/g00fy2/versioncompare/1.5.0/versioncompare-1.5.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/github/g00fy2/versioncompare/1.5.0/versioncompare-1.5.0.pom'.
> > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
> > Remote host terminated the handshake

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Command failed with exit code 1: C:\Webtrikon\quickchicken\platforms\android\gradlew :app:bundleRelease -b C:\Webtrikon\quickchicken\platforms\android\build.gradle
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

```
    cordova.cmd build android --release exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

how to solve this error, Stuck with it from past 4 days.